# Exclude directory from mod_autoindex.c Options -Indexes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-autoindex

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
# shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
# includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

However, I have a directory that does not have an index file (and I prefer to keep it this way), which I need to enable access.  How do I exclude this directory from the above code?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted and/or upvote it so I get credit and others who read this in the future see that it solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the following comment (I got this code from someone else):

```
# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document
```

...this code does not block users from accessing files in a directory that does not have an index file.  Therefore, I do not need to exclude my directory from the above code.

As an example, example.com/testdir does not have an index file.  But, I'm able to access example.com/testdir/testfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

Create an .htaccess file in that directory, and in it put the following

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options +Indexes
</IfModule>
```